# Alternative values should store in alternative position in array in php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

When the values fetching  from the mysql the values will be stored in series order in the array.  But i want the values to store in the array in alternative position. Here some individual values from table

---

*course_id('1') value*s

```
Array ( 
       [0] => 15BCA01 [1] => 15BCA02 [2] => 15BCA03 [3] => 15BCA04 [4] => 15BCA05 
       [5] => 15BCA06 [6] => 15BCA07 [7] => 15BCA08 [8] => 15BCA09 [9] => 15BCA10 
       [10] => 15BCA11
       )
```

---

*course_id('2') values:*

```
Array ( 
      [0] => 15MCA01 [1] => 15MCA02 [2] => 15MCA03 [3] => 15MCA04 [4] => 15MCA05
      )
```

---

*course_id('3') values:*

```
 Array ( 
        [0] => 15MBA01 [1] => 15MBA02 [2] => 15MBA03 [3] => 15MBA04 [4] => 15MBA05
        )
```

---

*course_id('4') values:*

```
Array ( 
       [0] => 15MSC01 [1] => 15MSC02 [2] => 15MSC03 
       )
```

---

*course_id('5') values:*

```
Array ( 
       [0] => 15TAM01 [1] => 15TAM02
       )
```

---

**when i execute the mysql command**

```
 select  register_number from master where master_course_id in('1','2','3','4','5');
```

**Current Output i am getting (as usual in series):**

```
Array ( 
        [0] => 15BCA01 [1] => 15BCA02 [2] => 15BCA03 [3] => 15BCA04 [4] => 15BCA05 
        [5] => 15BCA06 [6] => 15BCA07 [7] => 15BCA08 [8] => 15BCA09 [9] => 15BCA10 
        [10] => 15BCA11 [11] => 15MCA01 [12] => 15MCA02 [13] => 15MCA03 [14] => 15MCA04 
        [15] => 15MCA05 [16] => 15MBA01 [17] => 15MBA02 [18] => 15MBA03 [19] => 15MBA04 
        [20] => 15MBA05 [21] => 15MSC01 [22] => 15MSC02 [23] => 15MSC03 [24] => 15TAM01 
        [25] => 15TAM02
)
```

**Desired Output I want(alternative position):**

```
Array ( 
        [0] => 15BCA01 [1] => 15MCA01 [2] => 15BCA02 [3] => 15MCA02 [4] => 15BCA03 
        [5] => 15MCA03 [6] => 15BCA04 [7] => 15MCA04 [8] => 15BCA05 [9] => 15MCA05 
        [10] => 15BCA06 [11] => 15MBA01 [12] => 15BCA07 [13] => 15MBA02 [14] => 15BCA08 
        [15] => 15MBA03 [16] => 15BCA09 [17] => 15MBA04 [18] => 15BCA10 [19] => 15MBA05 
        [20] => 15BCA11 [21] => 15MSC01 [22] => 15TAM01 [23] => 15MSC02 [24] => 15TAM02 
        [25] => 15MSC03 
    )
```

If the first value in the array from **course_id ('1')** means the second values should be from **course_id ('2')** alternatively they should add in array.  If the **course_id ('1') completed** the **next course_id('3')** should start to **add** with current **course_id ('2')**. Like wise all the course_id values should add in the array alternatively. How to achieve this in php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL you need to use a user-defined variable to add ordering within the `master_course_id` groups.

```
SELECT register_number
FROM (
    SELECT master_course_id, register_number, 
        @position := IF(master_course_id = @prev_course, @position+1, 1) AS position, 
        @prev_course := master_course_id
    FROM (SELECT * FROM master 
          WHERE master_course_id IN ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5')
          ORDER BY master_course_id, register_number) AS m,
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @position := 0, @prev_course := null) AS vars
) AS t
ORDER BY position, master_course_id
```

The subquery adds an extra `position` column that counts up sequentially within each course ID. Then the outer query reorders everything by position first, then by course ID.

Comment: hi @Barmar i m checking.  i have to sustitute this in Yii framework and i will tell

Comment: hi @Barmar its working like   all the first position coming first                                                                                                     15BCA01, 15MCA01, 15MBA01, 15MSC01, 15TAM01,15BCA02,15MCA02,15MBA02 ............                                but i want like                                                                               15BCA01 ,15MCA01 , 15BCA02 ,15MCA02 , 15BCA03 , 15MCA03 ..........15BCA06 ,15MBA01 , 15BCA07 , 15MBA02  ,15BCA08 
 15MBA03 ..........15BCA11 ,15MSC01 ,15TAM01 ,15MSC02 , 15TAM02 ,15MSC03

Comment: I just reread the question, I don't understand the ordering you want. All those numbers look so similar it's hard to see the pattern.

Comment: If you need something more complicated than the order I did, you'll probably have to do it in PHP. Get all the register numbers into a 2-dimensional array, where the first dimension is the course ID. Then loop through the arrays in the order that you want.

Comment: @ Barmar superb its working i can manage the pattern in php.  Thanks a lot